# Replacing one string with other in C

Tags: c, string

I have a string

```
{&quot;status&quot;:true}
```

I want to replace `&quot` with `"`. I tried several string operations, but they're not working.

Comment: Could you show the *several string operations* you have tried so that we can see what might be wrong with them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c

Comment: @AmitApollo: `.Replace()` in C? `:S`

Comment: thought it was c#, missed that tag. nm

Comment: with strings the only recommendation would be strstr in C++, but I think it's the same for C, too, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Darin: there is no string operation which tells about "replace"

Comment: @user537670, does this answer my comment about what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replace (char *this, char *withthat, char *inthis) {
    char *where = inthis;
    if(strlen(withthat)>strlen(this)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "replace can only shrink\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((where = strstr(where, this))) {
        memcpy(where, withthat, strlen(withthat));
        memmove(where+strlen(withthat),where+strlen(this), strlen(where+strlen(this))+1);
    }
    return inthis;
}

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "{&quot;status&quot;:true}";
    printf("%s\n", replace("&quot;", "\"", string));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
{"status":true}
```