# __FILE__ Returns a String with "\/" in the Path

Tags: c++, gcc, path, windows-xp

I use the `__FILE__` macro for error messages. However, sometimes the path comes back as `E:\x\y\/z.ext`. It does this for specific files.

For example, `E:\programming\v2\wwwindowclass.h` comes back as `E:\programming\v2\/wwwindowclass.h` and `E:\programming\v2\test.cpp` comes back as `E:\programming\v2\test.cpp`. In fact, the only file in the directory that works seems to be `test.cpp`.

To work around this, I used jmucchiello's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c) to replace any occurrence of "/" with "\". This worked fine, and the displayed path changed to a normal one.

The problem was when I tried it on Windows 7 (after using XP). The string came up as `(null)` after calling the function.

Along with this, I sometimes get some seemingly random `error 2: File not found` errors. I'm unsure of whether this is related at all, but if there's an explanation, it would be nice to hear.

I've tried to find why `__FILE__` would be returning the wrong string, but to no avail. I'm using GNU g++ 4.6.1. I'm not actually sure yet if the paths that were wrong in XP were wrong in Windows 7 too. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: It is not returning the wrong string, it is just that this is one of the many implementation defined ways to deal with this. Often stuff needs \\ to escape \ properly, read the documentation for your OS on how it expects path names for the functionality it needs

Comment: But the true path being returned is `E:\\programming\\v2\\/wwwindowclass.h`. I don't see the use for that extra `/`. And why would it do that for most files, but not `test.cpp`?

Comment: @chris: Typically, the compiler does so when *you* pass `#include "v2/wwwindowclass.h"` to the compiler. Since every file has its own include statements, you can (but shouldn't) mix the two styles.

Comment: Ahhh, I see exactly what you mean now. My compiler just puts `/file.ext` on the end. I include my files like `#include "wwwindowclass.h"` and by default it puts in that slash. If I say `#include ".\wwwindowclass.h"` it shows up as `a\b\c\/.\wwwindowclass.h`. Would you make the compiler adding that slash onto the include into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MSalters's comment:

```
Typically, the compiler does so when you pass #include "v2/wwwindowclass.h" to the compiler. 
Since every file has its own include statements, you can (but shouldn't) mix the two styles.
```

This was the case. My compiler automatically adds a forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

The function in the linked question appears to return NULL if there are no changes to make. Probably Windows 7 doesn't suffer from the `\/` problem (in some cases).