# how to replace a string in an efficient way in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libc

I have a string which is generated by linux [uuid generation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/uuid_generate) code (libc):

```
1b4e28ba-2fa1-11d2-883f-b9a761bde3fb
```

I need to replace some of the characters in this string:

`-` with `_`
`2` with `f`
`4` with `x`

I am generating the 200 `UUID`s using a loop.

So for every uuid I need to replace using a custom function, so that function must be maximum optimised to do so, how can I attain that?

Comment: 200? That's not a large number, it would take some real work to not make this almost instant on a modern computer. Also, what do you have so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/779960

Comment: @Collin  I just have a uuid gen program which generates UUID in the above format  ,  can i use regular expression to do so , any example

Comment: @RobertHarvey : any optimized way like with out this much traversal

Comment: @johnchen902 
Replace every 2 with f if exists
Replace every 4 with x if exists
Replace every - with '_'

Comment: You can attain that by writing a program which does that. It's best to start early. If you have any problems, please post here.

Comment: Umm.... why don't you just loop over the string, `switch` on each char, and replace it accordingly? If the "-" are always in the same place, you can just hard code which bytes to override. Really can't get much more optimized than that...

Comment: @SchighSchagh , is it a good way "switch on each char, and replace it accordingly" for 200 uuids?

Comment: @RobertHarvey OP is replacing individual characters not substrings per se so this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: I did some testing on the different algorithms described here, see my post.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you're using `char[] str`

```
char *c;
for(c = str; *c != '\0'; ++c){
    if( *c == '-' ) *c = '_';
    else if( *c == '2' ) *c = 'f';
    else if( *c == '4' ) *c = 'x';
}
```

`switch` version

```
char *c;
for(c = str; *c != '\0'; ++c){
    switch(*c){
        case '-': *c = '_'; break;
        case '2': *c = 'f'; break;
        case '4': *c = 'x'; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about replacing with  regular expression

Comment: @Kajal replacing via regular expression is slower

Comment: @Kajal reg ex is overkill. I think writing it with a `switch` as I said in comment above instead of `if/else if` would be more readable, but it likely compiles to the same or very similar code.

Comment: You may be interested in the result of my testing.

Comment: @MattPhillips did you use `-O3` in your compiler argument?

Comment: @johnchen902 Good call, I did not--and also forgetfully ran it in release mode--and when I did, you win!

Answer (score 4):

Is something as trivial as this what you want?

```
void my_replace(char* str)
{
    while (*str) {
        switch (*str) {
        case '-':
            *str = '_';
            break;
        case '2':
            *str = 'f';
            break;
        case '4':
            *str = 'x';
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        ++str;
    }
}
```

It is really fast and simple. I really can't see how you can make it faster.

EDIT: I am aware of some optimizations in certain string operations, but I do not see how they can be applicable here. For example, in the case of `memcpy`, one may copy 4 or more bytes at a time, depending on the processor. In case of comparing strings that is properly aligned, comparing as integers may be possible and more efficient. I just can't see an applicable technique.

Comment: High performance libraries such as LAPACK and BLAS use finely tuned, processor-specific code (often in Assembly) to achieve speeds many times faster than what one can do in a high-level language, even for operations as simple as matrix multiplication.  I would expect the same is true of the C standard library as well.

Comment: @MattPhillips Your expectation is invalid. Have you tested the optimisations that your compiler implements, lately?

Comment: Have you?  What makes you certain that the C lib is not optimized?

Comment: As an example of what @Matt is saying, glibc employs SSE to optimise `memcpy`, `strnlen`, and other functions. In fact, several libc implementations do employ optimisations like this.

Answer (score 1):

C library functions may be optimized and significantly faster than a hand-coded iteration.

```
char* uuid; // = ...
//    size_t uuid_len; // = ... length of uuid


char* ptr = strpbrk(uuid, "-24");
while (ptr)
{
   switch(*ptr)
   {
      case '-':
          *ptr = '_';
          break;
      case '2':
          *ptr = 'f';
          break;
      case '4':
          *ptr = 'x';
          break;
   }
//       if (ptr-uuid == uuid_len) break;

   ptr = strpbrk(ptr+1, "-24");
}
```

Edit: Took out the range checking, on the basis of the example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strpbrk/) that doesn't seem necessary.

**Edit:** So I decided to test out the 3 algorithms here to see which is faster.  I had a loop of 100000 strings, on a vintage 2006 Mac Pro, compiling with gcc, -O3.  I took the average of 1000 runs and did 5 cycles.

### AND THE WINNER IS...

@johnchen by a *hair* with an average time of 7.85ms.

@YongweiWu just behind with an average time with 7.89ms.  The difference looks significant; going in and doing a proper statistical test is not going to happen tonight unfortunately. :)

...and `strpbrk` a distant third at 32ms.  (Glad I qualified all my optimization claims with 'might', 'may' etc....)

**Edit**: There is a big difference with Clang--j @ WY's algorithms take 10ms under Clang (looks tied between them), mine is unchanged.

Comment: @user93353 No, look at the last line.  After a character find `strpbrk` restarts at the next character, it does not start over at the beginning.