# I need a way to edit a string

Tags: c, string, char

Given a string like "/documents/filename.txt", I need to produce a new string "/documents/filename_out.txt", where the new string simply appends _out to the filename, while preserving the .txt suffix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){;
    char fileName[80];
    printf("Please enter filename: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    char outName[];

    printf("Outputname: %s\n", outName);
}
```

Is there a way to, say, remove the last 4 characters (.txt) from a string, then append the string with "_out.txt"?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with using `str{,n}{cpy,cat}()`?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do that. How else can we help you? Questions that ask "Is it possible?" or "Is there a way?" are not answerable here except by saying "Yes, it is" or "No, it isn't", neither of which are helpful to anyone. Please [edit] your question to make it more specific.

Comment: It seems to be solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c

Answer (score 1):

```
// strlen(".txt") = 4    
strcpy(filename + strlen(filename) - 4, "_out.txt");
```

You need make sure the buffer is big enough to contain the extra 4 more characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly specific solution to your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char newSuffix[] = "_out.txt";

    char fileName[80];
    printf("Please enter filename: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    char outName[85];

    strcpy(outName, fileName);
    strcpy(&outName[strlen(fileName) - 4], newSuffix);

    printf("Outputname: %s\n", outName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function `strtok` to tokenize your input and the concatenate them again, with _out between each token.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){;
char fileName[80];
printf("Please enter filename: ");
scanf("%s", fileName);
char outName[80];
char *name, *type;

name = strtok(fileName, ".");
type = strtok(NULL, ".");

snprintf(outName, 80, "%s_out.%s", name, type);
outName[79] ='\0';


printf("Outputname: %s\n", outName);
}
```

PS. I'm assuming the your input is always correct, so it isn't checking against anything except making sure that outName will always be a correct string by finishing it with NULL character.

Comment: thats a huge sledge hammer to crack a tiny nut. The strstr method is much much simpler.

Comment: @V-X This just a prove of concept, not a correct one in the sense to be safe at production time

Comment: @Steve Atkinson If you could learn a generic one that solve most of problem, and is simple to implement, why to be using one that you will change it very soom?

Comment: question is if the sledge hammer is able to hit it's target (imagine what may happen, when there are two dots in the filename)

Comment: So, all the others solutions suffer from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend. It is the first hit to the search query: "c substitute string". What you need is right here: [What is the function to replace string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
   char fileName[80];
   printf("Please enter filename: ");
   scanf("%s", fileName);
   char outName[];
   printf("Outputname: %s\n", replace(filename,".txt","_out.txt"));
}


char * replace(
    char const * const original, 
    char const * const pattern, 
    char const * const replacement
) {
  size_t const replen = strlen(replacement);
  size_t const patlen = strlen(pattern);
  size_t const orilen = strlen(original);

  size_t patcnt = 0;
  const char * oriptr;
  const char * patloc;

  // find how many times the pattern occurs in the original string
  for (oriptr = original; patloc = strstr(oriptr, pattern); oriptr = patloc + patlen)
  {
    patcnt++;
  }

  {
    // allocate memory for the new string
    size_t const retlen = orilen + patcnt * (replen - patlen);
    char * const returned = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * (retlen + 1) );

    if (returned != NULL)
    {
      // copy the original string, 
      // replacing all the instances of the pattern
      char * retptr = returned;
      for (oriptr = original; patloc = strstr(oriptr, pattern); oriptr = patloc + patlen)
      {
        size_t const skplen = patloc - oriptr;
        // copy the section until the occurence of the pattern
        strncpy(retptr, oriptr, skplen);
        retptr += skplen;
        // copy the replacement 
        strncpy(retptr, replacement, replen);
        retptr += replen;
      }
      // copy the rest of the string.
      strcpy(retptr, oriptr);
    }
    return returned;
  }
}
```

Comment: overkill for such a simple problem!

Comment: @SteveAtkinson: You may be right. Where you see overkill, I see complete generality.

Answer (score 0):

```
char outName[sizeof(fileName)+4];
strcpy(outName, fileName);
strcpy(strstr(outName, ".txt"), "_out.txt");
//strcpy(strrchr(outName, '.'), "_out.txt");
```

Comment: I was also wondering anxiety. But the addition of a check and leave to user2395925.