# replacing a character in string in C

Tags: c

Have to replace a user input character with another user input character and print the string . What am i doing wrong ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
int i;
char a,b,str[100];
printf("Enter the string");
gets(str);
//asking for replacement
printf("enter the character to be replaced");
scanf("%c",&a);
// which letter to replace the existing one
printf("enter the character to replace");
scanf("%c",&b);
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    if(str[i]==a)
    {
    str[i] = b;
    }
    else
    continue;
}
printf("the new string is");
puts(str);
}
```

Comment: Suggestion : use `fgets()` instead of `gets()`.

Comment: Note : change second `scanf()` to `scanf(" %c",&b);`

Comment: Note: `else     continue;`.. kind of redundant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace characters in C string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298679/replace-characters-in-c-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `getchar()` function between the two `scanf()`.

Like

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
        int i;
        char a,b,str[100];
        printf("Enter the string");
        gets(str);
        //asking for replacement
        printf("enter the character to be replaced");
        scanf("%c ",&a);
        //Get the pending character.
        getchar();
        // which letter to replace the existing one
        printf("enter the character to replace");
        scanf("%c",&b);
        for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
                if(str[i]==a)
                {
                        str[i] = b;
                }
                else
                        continue;
        }
        printf("the new string is");
        puts(str);
}
```

The problem is when you give a character and pressed enter, newline will acts as one character and it will be get by the next scanf. To avoid that the `getchar()` is using.

**Another Way:**

Give space before the access specifier on character to replace,

Like

```
scanf(" %c",&b);
```

But before remove that `getchar()`.

Comment: thankyou very much for this . But i still am not getting the right output . Also is there any way to still use scanf and to solve the problem of newline acting as a character ?

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

You get an integer ? not a character ? If it is a character, then you should use `%c` instead of `%d`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main() //main returns an int
{
int i;
char a,b,str[100];

printf("Enter the string\n");
fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);//gets is dangerous

printf("Enter the character to be replaced\n");
scanf(" %c",&a); //space before %c is not neccessary here

printf("Enter the character to replace\n");
scanf(" %c",&b); //space before %c is compulsory here
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    if(str[i]==a)
    {
    str[i] = b;
    }
    //else //This part is not neccessary
    //continue;
}
printf("The new string is ");
puts(str);
return 0; //main returns an int
}
```

I've used [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) because [`gets` is dangerous](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) as it does not prevent [buffer overflows](http://www.en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

The [space before `%c` in the `scanf`](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7166197/why-does-a-space-in-my-scanf-statement-make-a-difference) is to skip blanks,i.e,spaces,new-lines etc and it isn't needed in the first `scanf` is that `fgets` also consumes the new-line characters and puts it into the buffer.

The reason that the `else continue;` isn't needed is that the loop is going to check the condition as it has reached the end of the loop body.

I've used `int main()` and `return 0` because as per the latest standards,[it should](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

Finally,you have an unused header `conio.h` in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
  int i;
  char a,b,str[100];
  printf("Enter the string: ");
  gets(str);
  //asking for replacement
  printf("enter the character to be replaced: ");
  a = _getch();
  printf("\n%c", a);
  // which letter to replace the existing one
  printf("\nenter the character to replace: ");
  b = _getch();
  printf("\n%c", b);

  for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
  {
    if(str[i]==a)
    {
      str[i] = b;
    }

    else
     continue;
  }
  printf("\nthe new string is: "); 
  puts(str);
}
```

You can remove the `else` block. It won't affect anything.