# replace token in string

Tags: c, string

I have the following code:

```
char *repl_word(char *word, char *repl)
{
    const char *p1 = strstr(word,"<")+1;
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1,">");
    size_t len = p2-p1;
    char *src = (char*)malloc(len+1);
    if (src == NULL)
        return word;
    strncpy(src,p1,len);
    src[len] = '\0';
    char *find = "test";
    char *found;
    char *res = malloc(strlen(src) + strlen(repl) - strlen(find) + 1);
    if (res == NULL)
        return src;
    found = strstr(src, find);

    if (found == NULL){
        free(res);
        return src;
    }
    res[0] = '\0';
    strncpy(res, src, (size_t)(found - src));
    strcat(res, repl);
    strcat(res, found + strlen(find));
    return res;
}
```

which is working fine but only for the first occurrence of `"test"`. 
If word is `"<testtesttest1234>"` it doesn't replace everything.

How can I make it replace all occurrences of test in string word with repl?

Comment: It's because you don't loop.

Comment: yes, I know, but I don't know how to add loop not to affect malloc. Shall I use realloc or smth ?

Comment: The `malloc`d size doesn't have to be the exact size. You can just ignore everything after you "move" the string left (to replace) and add the null character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the function to replace string in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c)

Comment: it's confusing me because if no occurrence it must return src and after that res, so where exactly shall I add "while"? before found = strstr(src, find) ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know. My mind isn't working right now. If you are just writing one because there isn't a "replace" in C, you may be able to use the answer over on the link I gave.

Comment: I tried that solution but it doesn't replace anything, not even the first occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the code that removes the `<>` and just concentrate on the core of the question.

If you don't know in advance the length of the strings and replacements then you have a few choices:

1. Count the number of matches first and use that to work out the space requried
2. Use `realloc` in the loop to change the amount of memory allocated
3. Start with an intelligent guess at the size and then use realloc as required
4. Use fixed size buffers and just error out if we run out

The first is the simplest method, the one you want to use depends on what your performance requirements are (four is fastest at a cost of more memory if you have a good grasp on the max string size, three is probably the next fastest if you have a good idea of the average number of matches).

Implementing the simplest method just requires two loops, one to find the matches, then one to do the replacing:

```
char *strreplace(char *src, char* find, char *repl)
{
  char *target;    // Will store our new string
  char *final;     // Will use to store the pointer of the final string
  char *str = src; // Will use for searching
  int matches = 0; 

  // First count the matches (if strlen(repl) <= strlen(word) 
  // you could skip this and just allocate strlen(src)

  while (str = strstr(str, find)) { 
    matches ++;
    str++;
  }

  target = malloc(1 + strlen(src) + 
              (sizeof(char) * (matches * 
                       (strlen(repl) - strlen(find))
                   )));
  if (target == NULL) { 
    return src; // Or NULL, or whatever to indicate an error
  }

  final = target;

  // Now copy everything 
  str = src;
  while (str = strstr(str, find)) { 

    // Copy string before the match
    if (str > src) { 
      strncpy(target, src, (str - src)); 
      target += (str - src);
  src += (str - src);
    }

    // Copy replacement 
    strncpy(target, repl, strlen(repl));

    // Move pointers 
    str++;                  // Move past the match in our searching pointer
    src += strlen(find);    // Move past the string in our src
    target += strlen(repl); // Move past the replacement in our target

  }
  // Finally copy the rest of the string, if there's some left
  if (*src) {
    strncpy(target, src, strlen(src));
  }

  return final;
}
```

I think I might be using one too many pointers there, I have a feeling there's a simplification that can be done to the replace code but I can't see it at the moment.

You can take that and adapt it to do what you want, some tests (to try and cover the corner cases):

```
printf("%s\n", strreplace("testtesttest1234", "test", "foo"));
printf("%s\n", strreplace("testtesttest1234", "test", "foobar"));
printf("%s\n", strreplace("somethingtestsomethingteasesttest", "test", "foobar"));
```

Outputs:

```
foofoofoo1234
foobarfoobarfoobar1234
somethingfoobarsomethingteasestfoobar
```

Comment: I already solved it by modifying a little the answer to the suggested duplicate question, but for your time and effort I will accept your answer. Thank you!