# Generate correct path for RegSetValueEx()

Tags: c, path, registry

I am writing this C code that will store a Key in Registry which points in the current path of the application. Here is the code.

```
HKEY hKey;
LPCTSTR appPath;
LPCTSTR regPath = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
char buffer[300];

GetModuleFileName(NULL,buffer,300);
appPath = buffer;

if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,regPath,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&hKey)== ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
   RegSetValueEx(hKey,"storing.exe",0,REG_SZ,appPath,sizeof(appPath));
   RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

The problem is that GetModuleFileName() returns the path in that form :

`C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\storing.exe`

while in the RegSetValueEx() is expected a path in that form :

`C:\\Document and Settings\\User\\Desktop\\storring.exe`

Is there any way to convert the first path into the second one ? 
Tried many ways to replace that string but no one worked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c). 
This should be enough to solve your problem.

```
str_replace(appPath, "\", "\\");
```