# Replace XXX characters in character array to an int value in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, character-arrays, character-replacement

I have a character array of some size in C++ program

```
char current_time[30];
```

The value of the character array is 2015-02-24T21:39:02.xxx+0800

The "xxx" in the character array must be replaced with a three digit number which is stored in a integer.

How can I replace efficiently without using for loop in C++? The position of the XXX is also known in the character array.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c

Comment: I'm looking for a string functions to do easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of XXX in character array as x,y,z, you can update array as follows if your 3 digit number is N.

```
  int N2=N%100;
  int N3=N%10;

current_time[x]=N/100;
current_time[y]=N2%10;
current_time[z]=N3;
```

Comment: I'm looking for an in-built replace function. That replaces from the start position to end position with the given integer numbers.

Comment: Use std::string.replace()

Comment: When I use string replace, it overwrites xxx with a value I specify but it erases the +0800 from the character array/String. I just want to replace XXX without any damage to other characters.

Comment: It sounds like you might be calling std::string.replace() incorrectly for what you want to do if it's replacing the rest of your string. Please post what command you're using when you see that output

Comment: I apologize I got to know how to use String replace. But my problem is I have only character buffer not a string. And converting this character buffer to string and using replace is little bit lengthy. Is there a way to change the XXX characters alone directly from a character buffer ??

Comment: Convert to `string` at the first opportunity. Seriously, it makes everything much easier.