# Error in JSON string creation with / operator using jsoncpp library

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I am using JSONcpp library and facing problem to create json which contains / operator (like date : 02/12/2015). Below is my code:

```
JSONNODE *n = json_new(JSON_NODE);
json_push_back(n, json_new_a("String Node", "02/05/2015"));

json_char *jc = json_write_formatted(n);
printf("%s\n", jc);
json_free(jc);
json_delete(n);
```

**Output :**

```
{
    "String Node":"02\/05\/2015"
}
```

Check here  "`\/`" in date, we want only "`/`" in date, so my expected output should look like this:

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "String Node":"02/05/2015"
}
```

How to get rid of it? We are using inbuilt library function and we can not modify library.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this example](http://www.euphoriaaudio.com/index.php/2010/09/27/libjson-array-example/)

> The *json_new_a* method will escape your string values when you go to
>   write the final string.

The additional backslashes you are facing in the output are the result of adding escape characters. This is actually a good thing as it prevents both accidental and intentional errors.

I suppose the easies option for you would be to replace all `\/` occurrences in output string with single `/`. I wrote a simple program to do so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Here's the "json_char *jc" from your code
    const char* jc = "02\\/05\\/2015";

    //Replacing code
    string str(jc);
    boost::replace_all(str, "\\/", "/");

    //Show result
    cout << "Old output: " << jc << endl;
    cout << "New output: " << str << endl;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://cpp.sh/6vlc)

---

*BTW:* libJSON is not really a C++ library - it's much more C-style which involves many low-level operations and is more complicated and obfuscated than more C++ish libraries. If you'd like to try, there is a nice list of C++ JSON libs [here](https://blog.thousandeyes.com/efficiency-comparison-c-json-libraries/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but we did not use boost, we only use jsoncpp library and we are not passing string directly, we are using library inbuilt function

Comment: @pkachhia I see. Then, you could take advantage of something like these functions described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c . `json_char*` is basically pointer to `wchar_t` so it should work.

Comment: @pkachhia Are you able to access the string before printing it? Does the code look exactly like in the example you provided?

Comment: @PiotriSilwa we crosschecked buffer before passing to the library function json_write_formatted(), it looks exactly same (i.e. 02/05/2015). But when we print it after json_write_formatted() function it contains "\/" in output.