# Standard function to replace character or substring in a char array?

Tags: c, string, replace

I need a function from the standard library that replaces all occurrences of a character in a string by another character.

I also need a function from the standard library that replaces all occurrences of a substring in a string by another string.

Are there any such functions in the standard library?

Comment: Not really - you either have to write your own or look for a suitable third-party library.

Comment: 1. No, 2. No You'll have to write your own or migrate to C++

Answer (score 28):

There is no direct function to do that. You have to write something like this, using `strchr`:

```
char* replace_char(char* str, char find, char replace){
    char *current_pos = strchr(str,find);
    while (current_pos) {
        *current_pos = replace;
        current_pos = strchr(current_pos,find);
    }
    return str;
}
```

For whole strings, I refer to [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c)

Comment: Better to start searching from `current_pos+1` in the second `strchr`, to avoid O(n^2) running time.

Comment: @interjay You're right, I thought I had. Damn Shlemiel the painter's algorith :-)

Comment: Or, much more succinctly: `for (char* p = current_pos; (current_pos = strchr(str, find)) != NULL; *current_pos = replace);`

Answer (score 13):

There are not such functions in the standard libraries.

You can easily roll your own using `strchr` for replacing one single char, or `strstr` to replace a substring (the latter will be slightly more complex).

```
int replacechar(char *str, char orig, char rep) {
    char *ix = str;
    int n = 0;
    while((ix = strchr(ix, orig)) != NULL) {
        *ix++ = rep;
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

This one returns the number of chars replaced and is even immune to replacing a char by itself