# Replace a character in a string with a string in C

Tags: c, string, replace, substring, character

Let the following example code:

```
char s1[] = "Hey there #!";
char s2[] = "Lou";
```

I would like to write a function which replaces the **'#'** with the value of **s2**. Also it allocates memory dynamically for a new output string which has the new replaced version.
Is it possible in an elegant and non-complicated way, using mostly built-in functions?
I'm aware of how to replace characters with a character in a string or strings with a given substring but this one seems to beat me.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to go through severall functions, but... here goes:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[] = "Hey there #!";
    char s2[] = "Lou";

    // Get the resulting length: s1, plus s2,
    // plus terminator, minus one replaced character
    // (the last two cancelling each other out).
    char * s3 = malloc( strlen( s1 ) + strlen( s2 ) );

    // The number of characters of s1 that are not "#".
    // This does search for "any character from the second
    // *string*", so "#", not '#'.
    size_t pos = strcspn( s1, "#" );

    // Copy up to '#' from s1
    strncpy( s3, s1, pos );

    // Append s2
    strcat( s3, s2 );

    // Append from s1 after the '#'
    strcat( s3, s1 + pos + 1 );

    // Check result.
    puts( s3 );
}
```

This isn't as efficient as you could make it (especially the multiple `strcat()` calls are inefficient), but it uses only standard functions in the most "simple" way, and doesn't do any "pointering" itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32496721/5326843
According to this there is no standard function to replace a string. You have to write your own.

Comment: Yep, I know, but this is not what I want my desired output to be. I would like to replace a character in a string, with an another string, not with an another character.

Comment: Can't you just modifiy that function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single libc call, but possible with the use of multiple libc calls, something like below, no need of dynamic allocation.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    char* replace_string(char* str, char* find, char* replace_str)
    {
        int len  = strlen(str);
        int len_find = strlen(find), len_replace = strlen(replace_str);
        for (char* ptr = str; ptr = strstr(ptr, find); ++ptr) {
            if (len_find != len_replace) 
                memmove(ptr+len_replace, ptr+len_find,
                    len - (ptr - str) + len_replace);
            memcpy(ptr, replace_str, len_replace);
        }
        return str;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        char str[] = "Hey there #!";
        char str_replace[] = "Lou";
        printf("%s\n", replace_string(str, "#", str_replace));
        return 0;
    }
```

**output :**

```
Hey there Lou!
```