# String in C: replace characters with each other

Tags: c, string, character, string.h

For example, I choose a string "sd**oeoeeo**asd". I should replace all the 'o' with 'e' and vice versa: "sd**eoeooe**asd". I intend to do this with the `string` lib.

I found a pretty similar question ([Standard function to replace character or substring in a char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496497/standard-function-to-replace-character-or-substring-in-a-char-array/32496721)), but I don't get how to make the code work according to my condition. It happens that the first occurence of the character is replaced, and then the only one character replaces:

```
char* replace_char(char* str, char find, char replace){
    char temp = find;
    char *current_pos = strchr(str,find); 
    char *current_posc2 = strchr(str,replace); 

    while (current_pos) {
        *current_pos = replace;
        current_pos = strchr(current_pos,find);
    }
        while (current_posc2) {
        *current_posc2 = find; 
        current_posc2 = strchr(current_posc2, replace);
    }
    return str;
}
```

With `c1='e'` and `c2='o'` I get:

[image]

I have a thought about adding the third `temp` variable, but my suggestions of its implementation were wrong and didn't work.

Comment: try one loop: `char *replace_char(char *str, char find, char replace) { char *str2 = str; while (*str2) { if (*str2 == find) *str2 = replace; else if (*str2 == replace) *str2 = find; str2++; } return str; }`

Comment: Please, write your comment in the form of answer lower, in order to mark your code as the one that resolved my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one loop:

```
char *replace_char(char *str, char find, char replace) {
    char *str2 = str; // save str for return value
    while (*str2) {
        if (*str2 == find) *str2 = replace;
        else if (*str2 == replace) *str2 = find;
        str2++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
int i=0;
while(ch[i])
{
if(ch[i] == 'e')
ch[i]='o';
else if(ch[i] == 'o')
ch[i]='e';
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because it replaces all of the first character with the second character, then replaces all of the second character with the first character. It completely undoes the work of the first step in the second step. It's much simpler to just iterate through the string one character at a time, like in Bouraoui Al-Moez L.A's code.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use two loops

```
char *replace_char(char *str, char find, char replace) {
    char *ptr = str;
    while (*ptr) {
        if (*ptr == find) *ptr = replace;
        else if (*ptr == replace) *ptr = find;
        ptr++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

also you can use syntax array

````````````````````````
int j=0;
while(str[j] !='\0') // will loop on your string till the end of it
{
if(str[j] == 'e')  // if char=e will be o
str[j]='o';
else if(str[j] == 'o')  // if char=o will be e
str[j]='e';
j++;
}
```````````````````````
````````````````````````