# Is it a bug in str_replace?

Tags: c, string

I searched for a string replacement function and found this question

[What is the function to replace string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c)

If I use the code from the answer, it works but it looks wrong and gives a warning:

```
/home/dac/osh/util.c: In function ‘str_replace’:
/home/dac/osh/util.c:867:5: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
     for (count = 0; tmp = strstr(ins, rep); ++count) {
```

It looks like it's maybe a bug with `=` and `==` . Is it a bug or did I misunderstand? Should it be `==` instead?

Comment: It's probably not a bug. It will just run as long as `strstr` is returning non-zero.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok. But I should probably try and handle the warning somehow.

Comment: Is it your file/project? If so, handle it. But this is kind of style warning.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I took the code from the answer into my project and the code works. But gives a warning. Now I know how to handle it. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. In this case, the value of `tmp` is actually intended to be used as the condition.

The return value of `strstr`:

> ```
> char * strstr(char * str1, const char * str2 );
> ```
>
> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of `str2` in `str1`, or a null pointer if `str2` is not part of `str1`.

---

To remove the warning, try this:

```
for (count = 0; (tmp = strstr(ins, rep)) != NULL; ++count) {
```

Comment: Merely `(tmp = strstr(ins, rep))` will also remove the warning.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a bug. As per the body of the loop:

```
for (count = 0; tmp = strstr(ins, rep); ++count) {
    ins = tmp + len_rep;
}
```

it actually *uses* `tmp` for something. The continuation condition in that `for` statement will assign the result of `strstr()` to `tmp` then execute the body as long as it's non-zero (i.e., as long as it found the string). That's because `strstr()` returns `NULL` only if the string cannot be found.

I suspect this is just `gcc` being paranoid in that it realises the continuation condition (the middle bit) on a `for` statement *usually* tends to be a comparison and you may have accidentally used `=` rather then `==`.

That's why the diagnostic states `warning: suggest ...` rather than `error: what the heck?` :-) If you want to get rid of the warning (which isn't a bad position to take), simply do what it suggests and surround the entire continuation condition with parentheses.

Comment: It's useful to avoid using *yoda conditions*.

Answer (score 0):

[[ strstr reference ]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) states the return value for `char * strstr (char *str1,const char *str2 )` 
is :

> A pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of the entire sequence of
>   characters specified in str2, or a null pointer if the sequence is not
>   present in str1.

Now for a little more C terminology, when you do :

```
tmp = strstr(ins, rep)
```

the main intent of C is to evaluate the expression as a whole and C evaluates it to the return value of `strstr(ins, rep)` here. The side effect is assigning this return value to `tmp`. The error :

```
suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

is a way gcc helps you to avoid a careless mistake, say typing `a=b` instead of `a==b`, I believe. Note that in the first case the value of b is used as truth value, but in the second case the result of `is a equal b` is used a truth value. By putting a `()` around `tmp = strstr(ins, rep)` you give the compiler the green signal to evaluate the value of the expression as truth value.

**Side Note :**

Putting `()` around `tmp = strstr(ins, rep)` makes it a full expression, and full expression is considered as a sequence point. A sequence point is a point in program execution at which all side effects are evaluated before going on to the next step.