# Insert "E" after "T" in a string w/o tempering with "T"

Tags: c

The goal is to insert "E" after all occurrences of the letter "T"

But this is what the code below does:

Soon as the character "T" is detected...

It replaces "T" with another "T" then inserts "E"

How can it be altered so it does not replace "T" with another "T" because it seems like extra work.

Instead it can simply leave alone the existing "T" in place.. move AFTER it and insert the "E".

```
char s1[1024];
int i, n;

  for (i=0, n = 0; s[i]!= '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (s[i] == 'T')
    {
            s1[n] = 'T';
            n++;
            s1[n] = 'E';
            n++;
    }
    else
    {
        s1[n] = s[i];
        n++;
    }
}
s1[n] = '\0';
```

Comment: `s1` and `s` are different. Does what you intend mean to insert in `s`?

Comment: `s1` is the new modified version of `s`.

Comment: In that case T is not replaced by T but simply means copy.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, well everything else is copied regularly. why does T have to be copied in a special way ?. I suppose I asked the question wrong. but how do I ensure T is copied regularly ?

Comment: E.g `s1[n++] = s[i]; if(s[i] == 'T') s1[n++] = 'E';` or `if((s1[n++] = s[i]) == 'T') s1[n++] = 'E';`

Comment: Isn't this very much the same question as [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45367910/2371524)? Please don't "spam" questions but take some time before to clarify yourself what exactly you want to ask.

Comment: Didn't you just ask a nearly identical question about "%" -> "%%" a few hours ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy characters and when you see you have copied `T`, copy an `E`

```
s1[n] = s[i];
n++;    
if (s[i] == 'T')
{
  s1[n] = 'E';
  n++;
}
```