# Remove a substring from a string in C

Tags: c, string

I want to remove a particular substring from a string for example my main string is `"ababccdabce"` and I want to remove `"abc"` from it so it will become `"abcde"`.

I just wanted to know if there is a predefined function in C to do that, and if not, how to do it?

Comment: Why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: I suggest you try google with the title of your question here.

Comment: "predefined fuction in c " --> no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the function to replace string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no predefined function in C to remove a given substring from a C string, but you can write one using `strstr` and `memmove`.  Note that if you remove the substring in place, you cannot use `memcpy` nor `strcpy` because these have undefined behavior if the source and destination arrays overlap.

Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strremove(char *str, const char *sub) {
    size_t len = strlen(sub);
    if (len > 0) {
        char *p = str;
        while ((p = strstr(p, sub)) != NULL) {
            memmove(p, p + len, strlen(p + len) + 1);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Note that the resulting string may contain the substring as is the case in your example.

*Netherwire* suggested an optimisation:

```
char *strremove(char *str, const char *sub) {
    size_t len = strlen(sub);
    if (len > 0) {
        char *p = str;
        size_t size = 0;
        while ((p = strstr(p, sub)) != NULL) {
            size = (size == 0) ? (p - str) + strlen(p + len) + 1 : size - len;
            memmove(p, p + len, size - (p - str));
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Further honing the code, I came up with an even more efficient version using the 2 finger-method: only copying the fragments between matches starting after the first match:

```c
char *strremove(char *str, const char *sub) {
    char *p, *q, *r;
    if (*sub && (q = r = strstr(str, sub)) != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen(sub);
        while ((r = strstr(p = r + len, sub)) != NULL) {
            memmove(q, p, r - p);
            q += r - p;
        }
        memmove(q, p, strlen(p) + 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Here is the same method without any calls to `memmove`:

```c
char *strremove(char *str, const char *sub) {
    char *p, *q, *r;
    if (*sub && (q = r = strstr(str, sub)) != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen(sub);
        while ((r = strstr(p = r + len, sub)) != NULL) {
            while (p < r)
                *q++ = *p++;
        }
        while ((*q++ = *p++) != '\0')
            continue;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: You may decrease the number of `strlen` calls by caching `str` length, decreasing it each time the `sub` has been removed

Comment: @Netherwire: Good point, but it makes the code more cumbersome, especially if one wants to avoid computing `strlen(str)` if there is no match. Thanks for teasing me... I found an even better solution :)

Comment: `Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)` :)

Comment: @r1v3n: I fixed the special case where `sub` is an empty string. There might be other bugs, can you be more specific and tell me what arguments are causing the segfault?