# How to find the string in Flat array

Tags: arrays, c

I have a structure in which I have a flat array that store the list of strings and the offset will track the starting position where the string is added in the array.

```
typedef struct
{
   char element[256];
   int offset;
} A;

void A_append(A* a, const char *str) {
    // Concatenate on the end of element.
    strcat(&a->element[a->offset], str);

    // Increment the offset to the new end.
    a->offset += strlen(str);
}
int main() {
    A a = { .element = "" };
    a.offset = 0;

    char string1[] = "one";
    A_append(&a, string1);

    char string2[] = "two";
    A_append(&a, string2);
}
```

Now I want to search the string "two" in the flat array and then delete the string.

Please let me know if this feasible. If yes then how?

Comment: Two comments on that: you’ll need a delimiter to distinguish words, and to delete you need to pull up what follows the word to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `char* strstr(const char* string, const char* substring)`  function to find a substring within a string, e.g. `strstr(&a->element, "two")` which will return a pointer to the first occurrence of the substring within the string provided. There is no builtin C function to remove the substring automatically, but an example implementation using memmove is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116974/remove-a-substring-from-a-string-in-c).