# Stack around variable was corrupted - C

Tags: c, pointers, indexing, stack

i searched alot with google and spend about 2 hours fixing this error.
I get the following Error: 
 "**Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'buffer' was corrupted.**"

I know it has to do something with my pointers, my sprintf_s functions or similar. This simple program is supposed to just replace `','` with `'-'`.

I hope someone can give me a hint to solve this. I know a lot of those questions exist but none of them helped me fix this error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int strReplace(char *buffer, const rsize_t sizeBuffer,
    char *source, const rsize_t sizeSource,
    const char *substring, const rsize_t sizeSubstring,
    const char *replace, const rsize_t sizeReplace)
{
    if (sizeBuffer < sizeSource || sizeBuffer < sizeReplace || sizeSource < sizeSubstring)
        return -1;

    char *p;

    p = strstr(source, substring);
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        strncpy_s(buffer, sizeBuffer, source, p - source);

        buffer[p - source] = '\0';

        sprintf_s(buffer + (p - source), sizeBuffer, "%s%s", replace, p + strlen(substring));

        strncpy_s(source, sizeSource, buffer, sizeBuffer);
        p = strstr(source, substring);
    }

    return 0;
}

int myFunc(char *source, const rsize_t sizeSource)
{
    char *substring = ",";
    char *replace = "-";
    char buffer[100];

    strReplace(&buffer, 100, source, sizeSource,
        substring, 2, replace, 2);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char input[25] = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0";

    printf("input: %s\n", input);
    myFunc(&input, 25);

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should step through the `strReplace()` function in the debugger, and examine the variables after each step.

Comment: @Barmar already did that following every variable. Had no luck with that. Maybe i'm doing something wrong there

Comment: I don't think it should cause a problem, but `sizeBuffer` should be `sizeBuffer-(p-source)` in the `sprintf_s()` call.

Comment: Many implementations of string replacement can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c)

Comment: @Barmar no that's okay. It is supposed to append the buffer.

Comment: It's not OK because you're starting from `buffer + (p-source)`, so you have to substract that from the available space.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry i misread that comment. This solved it! If you provide a quick answer i will upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: When you have a function with 8 parameters and like 10 LOC, or when you have something like `const footype x` all over your function declarations, you should be concerned about the overall program design. Bad design gives bad code, and bad code gives bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHen you call `sprintf_s()`, you're starting from the middle of `buffer`. So you need to reduce the available space by that index. It should be:

```
    sprintf_s(buffer + (p - source), sizeBuffer - (p - source), "%s%s", replace, p + strlen(substring));
```