# C program to replace all occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: c

I want to write a C program to search all occurrences of a word in given string and
to write all occurrences of a word in capital letters.

Example

Input

Input string: good morning. have a good day.

Output
The word 'good' was found at location 1
The word 'good' was found at location 22

GOOD morning. have a GOOD day.

I wrote the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
  char str[1000], pat[20] = "good";
  int i = 0, j, mal = 0, flag = 0;
  printf("Enter the string :");
  gets(str);
  while (str[i] != '\0')
  {
    if (str[i] == pat[0])
    {
      j = 1;
      //if next character of string and pat same
      while(pat[j] != '\0' && str[j + i] != '\0' && pat[j] == str[j + i])
      {
        j++;
        flag = 1;
      }
      if (pat[j] == '\0')
      {
        mal += 1;
        printf("\n The word was found at location %d.\n" , i + 1);
      }
    }
    i++;
    if (flag == 0)
    {
      if (str[j + i] == '\0')
        printf(" The word was not found ") ;
    }
  }
  printf("The word was found a total of %d times", mal);
}
```

How can I convert the word 'good' into uppercase letters?

When i use the the functions toupper from the C library ctype.h, the entire text is converted into uppercase letters.
can you help me pleas?

Thanks

Comment: You need to store the start locations of the target word, like 1 and 22. And you know the length of the target word, too. So when you post-process your input string, use `toupper` within that region only (1-4 and 22-25).

Comment: Please properly format your code: proper indentation and remove unnecessary empty lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the function to replace string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c)

Comment: DAVID, If looking for "aba", should "xyx_ababa" print as "xyx_ABAba" or "xyx_ABABA"?

Comment: "i use the the functions toupper from the C library ctype.h, the entire text is converted into uppercase letters" --> post that use.

Answer (score 1):

Your code might crash if the there is no input.

Use the standard function `strstr()`. Why to reinvent the wheel? You can also improve the complexity of the code. See this link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/frequency-substring-string/

Answer (score -1):

I don't have permission to comment yet so I have to answer you here.

A `char` variable is encoded with 8 bits, so it can be 256 values [0,255].
Printable characters can be found in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com) where you can see that the character `a` is equal to the decimal value `97`.

If you consider characters as decimal value, I am sure you can figure out by yourself how to pass from `a (97)` to `A (65)`, so you will be able to perform the same operation for any character.

Comment: How about using `toupper()`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I guess his question was more about "how to convert a single character".

Comment: And what is wrong with `toupper()` to convert a single character? Note that not all platforms use ascii.